# CSS transition on a pseudo-element doesn't work the "second time"

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, pseudo-element

I am using a simple `:hover:after` in **CSS** to create a dark overlay on top of a div. I also am using `transition` property to make it fade in and out instead of simply appearing and disappearing.

Now, fading in it does brilliantly, but fading out, on the other hand, doesn't. It simply disappears as if there never was no `transition` to being with.

---

Here's the simplified code:
**HTML**:

```
<div class="innerImg"></div>
```

**CSS**(full code):

```
.innerImg {
    float: left;
    height: 74%;
    background-image: url("../images/an_image.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9F9F9F;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.innerImg:hover {
    border-color: #F8CE26;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
.innerImg:after {
    transition: all .2s ease;
    content: "";
}

.innerImg:hover:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

In desperation, I applied `transition` *everywhere*, but still, there were no changes. Originally, just putting it inside `.innerImg` and `.innerImg:after` was enough. In fact, it didn't work until I created just `:after` and gave that `transition`.

Anything stupid I'm missing here?

Comment: Just in case `::after` is a pseudo-element and not a pseudo class / state so it should be used with double colons.

Comment: @c-smile Oh, I forgot about that. Still, that doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you placed all the CSS properties that define the object's size on the hover selector. So when you aren't hovering over it, it has no size (and it disappears instantly).

What it looks like when not being hovered over:
[image: What it looks like]

What it should look like:
[image: What it should look like]

To fix, just move all of the size/layout properties from `.innerImg:hover:after` to `.innerImg:after`.

```
.innerImg:after {
    display: block;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.innerImg:hover:after {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

Demo (I slowed down the animation so it's easier to see):

```css
.innerImg {
  float: left;
  height: 74%;
  background-image: url("../images/an_image.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9F9F9F;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.innerImg:hover {
  border-color: #F8CE26;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.innerImg:after {
  display: block;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.innerImg:hover:after {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="innerImg">Hover over me!</div>
```